# how to check if client program is an original one in java

Tags: java, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get a good security for multiplayer game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423542/get-a-good-security-for-multiplayer-game)

I made a program with a server and clients they communicate with each other using sockets. I read on this blog that you can never fully hide your source code of a jar file. So can a client not just copy my source code and adjust it a little bit. For example where my program says level += 1; he could do level += 10;
So is it possible my server program can see if the client program is one i made?

Comment: do level += 1 at server side , or being cracked

Comment: You asked this question in a comment on your previous question, and I answered it there.  (And the short answer is No.)

Answer (score 0):

You are right.Your client jar could be decompiled and modified to send anything to your server.
But I think you are missing the point. Your server does not know who is the client accessing it (unless you use client authentication and you still delegate the security part to the user of the client program) so you should always program defensively when interacting with your clients. E.g. never trust input and always validate it. In your case if level is 10 verify if it is an acceptable input

Answer (score 0):

simple solution: you can override classloader of client application and load classes from 
 url/server. this way your class files doesn't need to be on the client side.

Comment: But is would be simple for a hacker to subvert that, and arrange that classes of *his* choice were loaded instead.

Comment: The security assurance is not something that a developer can make alone! environment, channel of communication etc also have to be secured! security model of ClassLoader in java is very rich but it doesn't and cant't guarantee security. look at [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1997/jw-09-hood.html)

Comment: if i wood do the classloader override would the client be able to see my source code then?

Comment: you can encrypt your class and decrypt with custom classloader however as i said complete protection is simply impossible :) see [this] (http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html) for more info